# Javascript: Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'count' has already been declared

Tags: javascript, html

Though the 'count' variable is not declared twice, I am getting this error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'count' has already been declared

Here is the code

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>Passenger Counter App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>People Entered</h1>
    <h2 id="count-el">0</h2>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
let count = 0
console.log(count)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
0
Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'count' has already been declared (at index.js:1:1)
```

Comment: You included the index.js twice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The index.js is imported twice(once in the head and then in the body). If you delete the one from the head then the error should go away.